# Getting a key corresponding to a specific value in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

I have a simple question about getting a key corresponding to a specific value in a dictionary in python. Please note I need only one command or one method(). No for loop, no writing def code, no map, or lambda etc., if there is a straightforward method() or command, please respond. If such a command does not exist in python, please create it and add it to the library. I suggest something like dic_inverse[value] or dic.inv(value) for the name of such a command.

Example: how to return the key corresponding to one specific value = 20 by one simple, clear, nice method() or command?

```
  dict = {'age': 20, 'height' : 154}
  dict_inverse[20] = ????
  or dict.inverse(20) = ????
```

Comment: There is no single method in the ```dict``` class to do that.

Comment: Try using the bidict package https://bidict.readthedocs.io/en/main/. It's a bi-drectional dictionary. It allows you to do things like `element_by_symbol['H']` and `element_by_symbol.inverse['hydrogen']`.

Comment: You said that there is no single method. I like your answer because I asked for a single method to do that. Now my question is, why can not create such a useful command (or method ()) and add it to the python library?  I am surprised such a command is lacking in python. Please respond to my question if you happen to  know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Creating and Looking up an inverse dict is as simple as it gets. You can abstract it into a function and pass in the dict and value to make your code cleaner.

```py
def lookup_by_val(d, val)
    inverse_dict = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}
    return inverse_dict[val]
```

P.S. You might wanna add error handling if you are not sure that input is not safe.

Comment: Thank you, it is a nice and short function. Although, I like it but in my question I asked a single method() or command not by writing a function. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you are talking about [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html). Make sure that the values are always unique, otherwise it will only return the first key associated with that value.

### Initializing Enum

First, you can initialize your Enum by setting up a class that inherits from the class `Enum`.

```py
from enum import Enum

class Person(Enum):
    age = 20
    height = 154
```

### Accessing Keys and Values

Then, you can get the corresponding value from a key.

```py
>>> print(Person.age.value)
20
```

Or you can do it backward, getting the key from a value.

```py
>>> print(Person(154).name)
height
```

Comment: I have not heard of Enum before. I like your solution specially it is a single command but again looks like the class has to be defined first and it required more work. Imagine your doing a lot single short code and you don't want to define a class for each code nor for each dictionary. Thank you though.